# Not able to update/modify map field in model spring jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have a model where I have json field which I have kept in a Map.

When I create this model through controller, all the fields get set properly.

But when I try to update the map and save it again through builder, the changes are not reflected in database (postgres). I am using auto generated setter method for setting the map field.

All the other fields are getting updated correctly.

Any reason why this could happen?

Comment: Let us see some code!

Comment: Please show some piece of code

Comment: Found the problem. It was happening because the field was set updatable=False. After changing it worked. My bad!